# I don't know why im I getting DioError Http status error [400] when sending comment from flutter app to .net core api

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm tryng to post a comment related to ceratin document in my app. I'm using .net core api and already have a working webb app. When i send comment I get an error saying:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]
I have web app where comment section is working just fine and object that is sent in mobile app is same as in web app. Example here :
`{documentId: 45, parentId: null, text: dsafd}`.
ParentId is for replying to another comment, so for new comment it should be null.

This is method for posting comment

```
onCommentSend() async {
    Client _client = Client();
    var data = {
      'documentId': widget.dokumentId ?? 0,
      'parentId': null,
      'text': commentController.text,
    };
    print(data);
    var res = await _dokumentiService!.addComment(data);
    print(res);
    if(data== true){
      print('Added comment');
    } else {
      print('not added');
    }
  }
```

And this is service method

```
 Future<bool> addComment(komentar) async {
    final response = await _client.post('/dokumenti/insertComment', data: komentar);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonresponse = response.data;
      print(komentar);
      print(komentar);
      return jsonresponse;
    } else {
      throw Exception('failed');
    print(Exception);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass data like this inside data of request :

```
 final response = await _client.post('/dokumenti/insertComment', data: jsonEncode(komentar));
```

and try this

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: can you share the response what you getting ?

Comment: I am hoping that there is base url is also there along with that _client.post : it will be like :  _client.post('${base_url}'+'/dokumenti/insertComment', data: jsonEncode(komentar));

Comment: I have copied first 3 lines of error because error is to long.  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]
E/flutter ( 7842): Source stack:
E/flutter ( 7842): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
E/flutter ( 7842): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
E/flutter ( 7842): #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:97:12)
E/flutter ( 7842): #3      DokumentiService.addComment (package:it4_dms_mobile/services/dokumenti_service.dart:58:36)

Comment: Request should be look like this : _client.post('${base_url}'+'/dokumenti/insertComment', data: jsonEncode(komentar));

Comment: I hava baseurl extracted in another class, and I made methods for fetching comments and documents that works. Fethcing documents : 
```Future<Dokument> getById(int id) async {
    final response = await _client.get('/dokumenti/get/$id');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonresponse = response.data;
      return Dokument.fromJson(jsonresponse);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }```

Comment: Can you share postman screenshot that working for you ? ypu can hide base url

Comment: Hardik thanks for your time, I found error it was typing mistake. 'documentId' was 'dokumentId' in backed. So the function was good only needed to rename it.